# Customize jQuery Validation's errorPlacement only for some fields

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I'd like to customize the `errorPlacement` only for certain fields, and defer to the plugin's default placement for the rest.  Something like:

```
errorPlacement : function(error, element) {
    if($(element).prop("id") === "mySpecialField") {
        $("#mySpecialErrorMessageHolder").append(error);
    }
    else {
        // this is not valid syntax but it's what I really want...
        super.errorPlacement(error, element);
    }
}
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
errorPlacement : function(error, element) {
    if($(element).prop("id") === "mySpecialField") {
        $("#mySpecialErrorMessageHolder").append(error);
    }
    else {
        error.insertAfter(element); // default error placement.
    }
}
```

[Looking at the source](https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation/blob/master/jquery.validate.js#L696), the default behavior is to use `insertAfter`.

Answer (score 6):

Use `error.insertAfter(element);`, which is the default:

```
errorPlacement : function(error, element) {
    if($(element).prop("id") === "mySpecialField") {
        $("#mySpecialErrorMessageHolder").append(error);
    }
    else {
        error.insertAfter(element);
    }
}
```